# In Cosmos, how do I use plugs properly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, operating-system, cosmos, hobby-os

I'm in the process of creating my own operating system with Cosmos, but I have a problem.

I need help with **plugs**! So far I've managed to write my operating system using code that doesn't require plugs. But this makes my OS *really limited.* I can't even make it display the *time!* Also, in a program I wrote called Math-Man, I can hardly make it do anything. For example, when I write
Math.Pow..., I get the build error "Native code encountered. Plug required."

I don't quite understand how to "use" plugs in Cosmos.

If someone could tell me how to make Math.Pow work, I'm more than sure I could figure out how to make the other busted code (like the code bits that get the time and stuff) work as well.

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: Thanks for updating.   Comment removed